# How to get Longitude and Latitude of user? I also wanted to convert that in an address as precise as possible

Tags: android, android-location

//Got this class from stackoverflow itself
    package com.example.locationprovider;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
{
private final Context mContext;

//flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

//flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

//The minimum distance to change updates in metters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

//The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

//Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    try
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)
mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            // no network provider is enabled
        }
        else
        {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            //First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                Log.d("Network", "Network");

                if (locationManager != null)
                {
    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }

            //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled)
            {
                if (location == null)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

    return location;
}

public void updateGPSCoordinates()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS()
{
    if (locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 */
public boolean canGetLocation()
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.GPSAlertDialogTitle);

    //Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.GPSAlertDialogMessage);

    //On Pressing Setting button
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //On pressing cancel button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */
public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context)
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            return addresses;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Try to get AddressLine
 * @return null or addressLine
 */
public String getAddressLine(Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

        return addressLine;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Locality
 * @return null or locality
 */
public String getLocality(Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        return locality;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Postal Code
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getPostalCode(Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

        return postalCode;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get CountryName
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getCountryName(Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String countryName = address.getCountryName();

        return countryName;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{   
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{   
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{   
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{   
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
}
```

// Here is my main Activity class.
//I am trying to make an app which sends the users current location as a text message to a //specified number.

```
package com.example.locationprovider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements OnClickListener{
Button setNumberButton, shareLocationButton;
DataBaseHelper baseHelper = null;
Cursor cursor = null;
SQLiteDatabase database;
String num;
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setNumberButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setNumberButton);
    shareLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareLocationButton);
    setNumberButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    shareLocationButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Create Database here
    baseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    baseHelper.createDateBase();
    //Opening database
    database = baseHelper.openDataBase();
    String col[] = {"number"};
    //Getting the number from database
    cursor = database.query("phoneNumber", col, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        //cursor was getting past values too.
        //But now, only last value inserted will be used as a number.
        while(cursor.moveToLast()){
            num = cursor.getString(0);
            //Showing current set number as a toast.
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Current number : " + num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }}
    else
        num = "";       
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   
public String getLocation(){
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
if(gpsTracker.canGetLocation()){
        String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
        String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
        String country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(this);
        String city = gpsTracker.getLocality(this);
        String postalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(this);
        String addressLine = gpsTracker.getAddressLine(this);

        return country;
    }
    else
    {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        String a = "No location";
        return a;
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.setNumberButton://send to set number activity ..
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetMessageNumber.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.shareLocationButton: //send message ..
            String textMessage = getLocation(); //Text message to be sent
            // Testing by creating a toast instead of sending text!
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location :" + textMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /*try {
                //Making a SMS manager object
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, textMessage, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "SMS failed...",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         e.printStackTrace();               }*/
            break;
        }       
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/?

Comment: Yes I have.. The thing is that this code only gives the position when I move. What should I change so that it gives me the position of the user even if he isn't moving.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private String city,currentlocation,locality,country,zipcode;

    GPSTracker gpstracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity(), 0);
            // latitude and longitude
            double latitude = gpstracker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gpstracker.getLongitude();
        try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                if (geocoder.isPresent()) {

                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    currentlocation = returnAddress.getAddressLine(0);
                    city = returnAddress.getAddressLine(1);
                    locality=   localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    country = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();
} else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "geocoder not present",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want continuous updates from the phone independent of whether it has moved or not, then all you have to do is set the values of both `MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES` and `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` to 0.

Note that doing so is highly discouraged as this puts high demands on the battery and other resources.

If you are looking for just a one-time update just use the method:

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, pendingIntent);
```

For more details on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html